# How can I redirect the error stream from ruby's shell commands in vim's ruby interface?

Tags: ruby, vim, rake, stderr

I want to use the `rake` module from vim's ruby interface to run rake files. When a rake task uses `sh` to call shell commands, the output goes directly to the terminal - it doesn't go through ruby's `$stdout` and `$stderr` - when I try to redirect `$stdout` and `$stderr` the output doesn't go to where I redirect it.

Now, in vim, that output does not go to vim's terminal - it goes to the terminal that launched vim!

`stdout` is not a problem, because rake prints it where I want it. However, if I try to use the rake module from vim's ruby interface, I don't want the error output to go to the terminal who called vim(which is hidden when running gVim and awkward when running shell vim) - I want it to go into something I can read via ruby or vimscript(so I can parse the error message)

So, I'm looking for a way to:

- Read\Redirect `stderr` of ruby's shell calls, or
- Read\redirect the `stderr` that vim sends to the shell that called it.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

If you use `2>` when calling Ruby or rake, it will output `stderr` to where you want it.

Will output error to console:

```
ruby -e "raise 'exception'" > output
```

Will output error out file called `output`:

```
ruby -e "raise 'exception'" 2> output
```

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: Thing is, I prefer to avoid using the command line interface to rake. I'd like to use the API instead, so I can catch the exception thrown by rake directly in vim's ruby interface.